# Does composer-playground directly read local connection.json or read properties from my web browser cache?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I'm going to using composer-playground for connecting my own fabric instance.Here is my env:
OS:Ubuntu16.04
installation method: npm install -g composer-playground
start method: #composer-playground

At first time i created a profile myconn1 from url:http://localhost:8080/profile,and a connection.json was generated in path /root/.composer-connection-profiles/myconn1.
 Then i exit the process composer-playground,modify the connection.json file.
 But after starting again composer-playground, my new connection.json was overwritten by my first time  web page configuration.
 Is there another location where storage the connection info?
If i want to use specified  the connection  profile,how do i start my composer-playuground?

Answer (score 0):

Playground stores connection profiles in the browser local storage. However in order to make a connection to the external blockchain it needs to write it to a filesystem to be used by the server side implementation in order to establish the connection to the blockchain.
Playground should support the ability to export and import connection profiles so that would be the suggested way if you want to alter them outside of the playground environment.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this guide to install and run Playground locally:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/getting-started-playground.html